# Difficulty seeing how two combinatorial identities are equivalent?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In my textbook for discrete mathematics they state the following theorem (followed by proof):

(i)  $C(i + 1, k) = C(i, k - 1) + C(i, k)$

The proof of the above statement that is provided makes sense to me. However, a couple of examples later, they claim that this statement is equivalent to:

(ii)  $C(i, k) = C(i + 1, k + 1) - C(i, k + 1)$

I am having a hard time understanding why they are equivalent and was hoping somebody might be able to show me how (i) could become (ii).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that the second identity is equivalent to 
$$\binom{i + 1}{k + 1} = \binom{i}{k} + \binom{i}{k + 1}$$
If we let $j = k + 1$, then $k = j - 1$, so we obtain
$$\binom{i + 1}{j} = \binom{i}{j - 1} + \binom{i}{j}$$
Compare this with the first identity.

Comment: Thank you! This is off topic, but I am 99% sure that you were one of my math teachers in high school. I couldn't figure out how to send a user message, so I won't say more than that, but what a small world!

Comment: I am guessing that means you are Daniel Levi-Minzi.

Comment: Yep hahaha. Please accept my very late apology for any times I was annoying in your classes. Hope things are going well on your end!